# ST_ReducePrecision function does not work properly

Tags: postgis, well-known-text, precision, power-bi

I am trying to use **ST_ReducePrecision** to reduce the number of characters, because of the character limit in power bi cells.

`ST_AsText(ST_ReducePrecision(ST_Transform(geom, 4326), 0.000001))`

The result that I'm geting is not what I was expecting:

**Original WKT:** MULTIPOLYGON(((-42.49076772971744 -22.940101731323654,-42.492057937951515 -22.9399517863236,-42.492703038099 -22.93987681565973,...

**Using ST_ReducePrecision:** MULTIPOLYGON(((-42.492058 -22.939951999999998,-42.492703 -22.939877,-42.493992999999996 -22.939726999999998,...

**Expected result:** MULTIPOLYGON(((-42.490768 -22.940102,-42.492058 -22.939952,-42.492703 -22.939877,...

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Unfortunately, your expectation  is incorrect. The precision of the data did change, but that does not change unformatted presentation in ST_AsText.

Answer (score 5):

This is a GEOS bug that was fixed recently in [GEOS-956](https://github.com/libgeos/geos/pull/956).  It's in GEOS 3.12.1, so upgrading might solve this problem.

Answer (score 4):

[ST_ReducePrecision](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ReducePrecision.html) changes the precision of the numeric values.

[Floating point numbers are hard for computers](https://jvns.ca/blog/2023/01/13/examples-of-floating-point-problems/) so when you want them as text, weird issues can occur.

Try [ST_AsText](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsText.html)'s `maxdecimaldigits` parameter in addition to it.

Comment: `ST_ReducePrecision` *also* ensures that reducing the precision of polygonal inputs maintains correct topology so that the output is valid.

Comment: Oh nice, i edited my answer. Would st_reduceprecision always lead to st_astext using its precision once the geos bug is fixed?

Comment: Yes, it should.

Comment: Thank you, I think I solved the problem using ST_AsEWKT:

ST_AsText(ST_AsEWKT(ST_Transform(geom, 4326), 6))

Is this ok?